# Java POI "shiftRows" doesn't work correct

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I try to compare two different Dates (first date = now +5 Years, memorized in a variable with the name future and second Date from a excel sheet for each cell in a row) and if one of them is after the firestone then I would like to remove it. The remove is working good but I have big problems with the Function shiftRows. It doesn't work, and I have no idea why not! Could someone help me to resolve the Problem?

```
for(int i = zeile + 1; i <= lastRowNum; i++) {
    Row row1 = sheet.getRow(i);
    String dateStr = row1.getCell(spalte).getDateCellValue().toString();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);

    Date date1 = null;
    try {
        date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (date1.after(future)) {
        sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));   // remove Row, works good!
        if (i >= 0 && i < lastRowNum) {
            sheet.shiftRows(i+1, lastRowNum, -1);   // shiftRows doesn't work!?!?!?! Need help!
        }else if (i == lastRowNum) {  //special removing if the last row ist one of them witch should be removed
            Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: It is unclear *what* doesn't work in `shiftRows`.  Are you getting an error? Does it do something wrong? Does it do nothing?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Hauptanwendung.Hauptfenster$2.actionPerformed(Hauptfenster.java:191)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: @hamza I'm not seeing any POI code in your exception, looks like your own code that's breaking?

Comment: at (Hauptfenster.java:191) is: String dateStr = row1.getCell(spalte).getDateCellValue().toString();

Comment: I don't know, but if I coment the line with    sheet.shiftRows(i+1, lastRowNum, -1);   the program works but if use it it brings me this Exception!

Comment: I am although confused of this exception because there is not any POI code in the exception!

Comment: It's a `NullPointerException` so either `row1` is null or `row1.getCell(spalte)` gets null. Check that before using the objects further.

Comment: Your for-loop indexing looks dangerous when combined with either shiftRows or removeRow, since the row indices change below the shift/deletion point. LastRowNum may be beyond the last row, i may need to be rewound or fast-forwarded. Figure out what the workbook looks like immediately before and after the shiftRows is called (by writing the workbook out to a file and examining the workbooks in Excel/LibreOffice) and print the arguments to shiftRows. If the behavior is incorrect, open a bug at poi.apache.org.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I have been using a static value for the Inex lastRowNum instet to reed the Index ewery loop in the for-loop. The solution is but every time read the Index (sheet.getLastRow()) just because standing columns will be, deleted and moved. And I needed also after sheftRows an negative Inkrementator i--;                        Thanks to all of you for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
This code works:


for(int i = zeile + 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    Row row1 = sheet.getRow(i);
    String dateStr = row1.getCell(spalte).getDateCellValue().toString();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);

    Date date1 = null;
    try {
        date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (date1.after(future)) {
        sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));   // remove Row, works good!
        if (i >= 0 && i < sheet.getLastRowNum()) {
            sheet.shiftRows(i+1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
            i--; 
        } else if (i == sheet.getLastRowNum()) {       
            Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```